# Selenium Webdriver Resolution issue?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Unable to run the selenium webdriver script, when the system resolution is high. when it's scroll down the few elements are not capturing. So I don't know how to resolve this.

Comment: Add a wait. Wait till you find the element, and continue scrolling till you get to the element.

Answer (score 1):

Add `implicitwait` by default to all the elements if you feel that few elements are taking long time to load just put `explicitWait` for those elements

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can handle resolutions using Selenium by Setting properties for desiredcapabilities :

```
  DesiredCapabilities dc=new DesiredCapabilities();    
  dc.setCapability("screen-resolution","1280x1024");
```

Comment: we can handle in both ways.

Comment: So why not put both in one answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve scroll down issue finding the element PageDown which is part of scrollbar element.
Eg

```
this.Session.FindElementByAccessibilityId("PageDown").Click();
```

Another option is pressing the key "PageDown" as much times as you need into your session(driver) scope.

Eg

```
this.Session.Keyboard.SendKeys(Keys.PageDown);
```